# Stuck In Login Loop Ubuntu 20.04 (INFINITE)

Tags: login

I use **Ubuntu 20.04**. **Budgie desktop + Plasma + Pantheon**. I am stuck in login loop. **Have dual -boot. Windows and Ubuntu**. Recently, suddenly i got login loop. Tried everything on internet, nothing worked. Actually i tried installing Xubuntu it worked. But no background in Xubuntu. All apps DID NOT WORK. Problem with graphics maybe. And budgie, plasma and pantheon still not working. Now Xubuntu also not working......Still in login loop..... PLEASE HELP! I tried reinstalling. That also did not help. I tried playing with .Xauthority and .ICEauthority and everything else.I mean chowning and trying removing them. Didn't help. I remember it happened after a windows update.(A small one). Sometimes i try to use startx. But it sometimes says [xinit:connection to x server lost]. This is new issue than others. SO i need help.

Comment: Have you logged into terminal, and ensured you have space in $HOME (your user directory). A GUI login requires work files to be created there, and if there is insufficient space the login will fail and you're logged out (no message). Making changes to other files if this is your issue doesn't help (and telling us you *playing with .Xauthority* without details doesn't help us to help you)

Comment: Actually i had tried removing. Xauthority file and tried chowning. This is what i mean by playing with them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nVidia graphics card, use these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-367
```

If it succeeds, reboot.

```
sudo reboot
```

If it doesn't work, try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/223634/549097).

Comment: Nvidia 367 isnt supported with my lap.

Comment: Problem is not with xserver. My father is trying to see errors. Its with graphic. I know you answered but 367 isnt supported

Comment: Actually my lap uses 390 and 440 and xserver-video... But i got stuck in login loop suddenly. When i tried to remove splash from GRUB_CMDLINE_DEFAULT: It didnt boot. So i removed it and again like before. It is really a different and new issue.