# Stuck in Login loop Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, login, login-screen, gdm

I am stuck in  a login loop after restarting and have tried eveything below:
[Stuck In Login Loop Ubuntu 20.04 (INFINITE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270182/stuck-in-login-loop-ubuntu-20-04-infinite),
https://www.makeuseof.com/fix-ubuntu-login-loop-issue/,
https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-ubuntu-login-loop/,
https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-ubuntu-login-loop/,
https://letsfoss.com/ubuntu-login-loop-fix/,
https://sourcedigit.com/25447-how-to-fix-the-ubuntu-login-loop-problem/,
, including removing all nvidia drivers and reinstalling.
Any ideas?

**EDIT**
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. I worked out the problem in the login loop, it turned out to be a corrupted hidden .configuration file in my user. So I moved them all into a sub-folder and was able to login. This lost all of my configurations but is a small price to pay.  I compiled  a list of solutions from various sources [here](https://medium.com/@joseph.rowell/ubuntu-20-04-login-loop-db5e02025c83).

Comment: Major reasons for login loop are lack of space in $HOME, **or** a change made by a `sudo` user on that system in the session prior to the issue  (*if it was an update; you can bypass that by booting a prior kernel at grub in a few secs*).  Why not tell us what change(s) were made before this issue occurred?