# Restore Deja Dup from root?

Tags: deja-dup

My Ubuntu 20.04 system is stuck in a login loop for one of the users, so I have narrowed it down to be a problem in one of my hidden files in my /home/*username*/ directory.
Luckily, I have a backup from a couple of days ago using deja dup, and I am able to login and access tty3. From this, I can "sudo su" and "startx", and then access the deja dup GUI.
My question is, can I restore deja dup from root without any problems? And if I do, do I set "original file locations" or specify my user?

**EDIT**

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. I worked out the problem in the login loop, it turned out to be a corrupted .configuration file in my user. So I moved them all into a sub-folder and was able to login. This lost all of my configurations but is a small price to pay.  I compiled  a list of solutions from various sources [here](https://medium.com/@joseph.rowell/ubuntu-20-04-login-loop-db5e02025c83).

Comment: In my experience it doesn't work well as root. The developer discusses it here https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/deja-dup/-/issues/142  I'd suggest restoring to a new location, renaming the old user's home, then renaming the restored location to be the user's home. Delete the renamed user directory once you've confirmed all is well.That has worked for me.

Comment: You're asking about Ubuntu Core 20?  (the *year* products (20) are intended for headless operation being a *flavor* of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server, or are your release details incorrect?)

Comment: Try "sudo -E dejadup"

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a space issue?  If insufficient space exists in a user directory; GUI logins will not proceed  (your `sudo su` will cause the GUI to start using the `/root/` user account & thus avoid any space issue in `/home/$USER`)

Comment: Please make that an answer including the important parts from the link including source references, That way the q can be marked as answered and it will not show backup in the active queue. Otherwise this might get closed.

Comment: and this was asked twice (the other one about the login loop) and has the same edit: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1463507/stuck-in-login-loop-ubuntu-20-04?noredirect=1